# initializing a rownum value for MYSQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that is working fine when I run in through phpMyAdmin directly as SQL, but when I try and do this in PHP it doesn't work. I suspect the problem is because I'm trying to return a rownum value from a generated table and the `SET` command on the first line doesn't work. Here is an example query that is working as expected as SQL:

```
SET @rownum =0;
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT i.*, @rownum := @rownum +1 AS row,  (
        SELECT COUNT( * )FROM _votes WHERE i.id = image_id) AS total_votes, 
        (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM _votes WHERE i.id = image_id AND voter_id = 67) AS voted 
        FROM _images AS i WHERE i.approved = 1 ORDER BY total_votes DESC ) 
    AS T WHERE entrant_id IN (68,69,70,71)
```

(please forgive my formatting if it is incorrect)

Two things:

- Is this query too long and inefficient?
- How do I initialize the @rownum value to zero if this is coming from a php prepared statement?

I've tried adding `JOIN (SELECT @rownum :=0) r` to the end of the query but that doesn't work.
Also I've tried this joining method unsuccessfully at various points within the query.

*php*

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT i.*, @rownum := ...
```

Comment: Do you need @rownum in PHP? You can accomplish the same thing by setting a counter when you look the rows.

Comment: I'm trying to return the ranking of a selection of users from a leaderboard, so I thought the row numbers won't always match this position.

Comment: If you sort the result set, than the rows will be in the correct order.

Comment: yeah but for example if only two results are returned, they will be in the correct order but I need to know the actual position on the leaderboard which most likely isn't 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET` queries are distinct queries, and you can only send one query at a time through PHP. So, run the `SET` query, then run the second query. The MySQL server will remember your setting if you use the same connection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on the purpose of using @rownum variable; perhaps there might be other ways to do so.

But anyways, the issue with your query is that with PHP's MySQL library you cannot send multiple queries in the same run. You'll have to send them as 2 queries and if done in the same connection, MySQL will not loose the value in @rownum.

Another alternative is that you use the MySQLi library that has a function to run multiple queries - multi_query(). This is only a suggestion because I'm not sure how tricky it might be for you to use MySQLi.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm using prepared statements which don't work with multi_query, so I have had to do two distinct queries on the same connection.